# How did the house-elves become enslaved to wizards?

Tags: harry-potter, house-elves

House-elves are magical creatures, that are bound to serve their wizard masters until death, unless they're given an article of clothing. How did they become enslaved? Did wizards create them? Are they enchanted? Did they willingly put themselves under this, since they actually ENJOY the slavery?

**How did the house-elves become bound to their wizard masters?**